# Lumen - Middleware registered as singleton is not a singleton

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-middleware

The expected behavior is each response has a `X-Cont` header with an incremented number:

- 1st request/response header `X-Cont` is 1
- 2nd request/response header `X-Cont` is 2
- 99th request/response header `X-Cont` is 99

Here is my middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class MyMiddleware {

    private $cont = 0;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $response = $next($request);
        $this->cont++;
        $response->header('X-Cont', $this->cont);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I registered my middleware in my application service provider:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    public function register(){
        $this->app->singleton(MyMiddleware::class, function ($app) {
            return new MyMiddleware();
        });
    }
}
```

And enabled the middleware and service provider in the `bootstrap/app.php`

```
...
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class
]);
...
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

But all request/responses has `X-Cont` header 1. If this middleware is a singleton class it should increment `$cont` variable.

What am I missing here?

Comment: the request comes in, the response goes out and the process dies ... the entire framework is booted on every request; it is not a single long running process

Comment: @lagbox that makes sense. So the container return the same singleton instance if the object is requested from differents points inside the same process? It could seems obvious but I have no PHP or Lumen background, I'm learning.

Comment: yes to your question ... you can look at it as a request response lifecycle ... the main `index.php` script is hit and that starts the process of booting the framework and passing the request in, a response eventually comes out and the application finishes what it does and the process dies ... might seem odd but that is how the PHP world works for the most part ... you can read up on the request lifecycle in Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/lifecycle

Comment: This information gives to me a completely different perspective xD
Thank you!

Comment: @lagbox now I know the whole framework boots with every request, I have some more doubts about it. How PHP, Lumen, Laravel handles cache or stateful session based applications? Where all this info goes?

Comment: if it is not 'stateless' you can use sessions to persist information across requests for a User, but Lumen is only for stateless APIs so you would want to use Laravel then ... if you are going 'stateless' you still have a cache store you can use to persist data but it would be via the Cache system so more generically for the application and not a user itself  ... for what you are doing if you are only incrementing a number for every request regardless of who the client/user is then you can just use the cache system to store that variable, increment it and return it